# uninitialized constant DeviseController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting uninitialized constant DeviseController which I explicitly require the Devise gem in Rails project rather than using Bundle.require in application.rb

I have the following in application_controller.rb:

```
require 'devise'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
```

But devise_controller? invokes ::DeviseController and for some reason it is not defined. What is going on here?

Comment: Why are you using include `Devise::Controllers::Helpers` here ? I'm not sure, if that has caused the issue. Can you try removing that line ? Also, why is there `require`? Have you not installed `Devise` ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I have devise with require: false in Gemfile so I have to explicitly require it. I added the module because I was getting undefined method devise_controller if I did not include the module. I downloaded Devise gem and read through source code and it was defined in that module. But the mysterious DeviseController class is defined in global scope yet not detected.

Answer (score 3):

The use of `require` in a Rails app is a red flag. It should rarely be used unless you create your own functionality outside of the scope of your MVC (which would usually be placed in the `lib` directory)...

Assuming you have installed devise...just remove your `require` and `include` statements...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
end
```

And all should be well if you have a private method named `configure_permitted_parameters` ie...(with your appropriate custom attributes and action)

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username])
end
```

Comment: I had a requirement to not use Bundle.require in application.rb and therefore have to explicitly require the gems